# custom column checkbox formatter using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datagridviewcheckboxcell, checkboxpreference

I have to add checkbox in one of the column (middle column) .. I supposed to make some row non editable checkbox .. All i need to know is how do i implement select all option for the header .. it's not coming up in the grid .. i have already set **multiselect:true**

```
columnDisplay = [{"name":"columnId",
                    "label":"Column Id",
                    "type":"string" ,
                     hidden:true,
                     "width":"200",
                     key:true
                  },
                  {
                   "name":"columnDisplayName",
                   "label":"Column Display Name",
                   "type":"string" ,
                   "visibility":true, 
                   "width":"200"
                   },

                   {
                   "name":"visibility", 
                   "label":"Visibility",
                   "editable": true, 
                   "width":"200",
                   "edittype": "checkbox",
                   "editoptions": { value:"Y:N" }, 
                   "formatter": "checkbox", 
                   "formatoptions": { disabled: false}
        }];


createjqGrid : function (gridId , column , gridData){
                $("#" + gridId).jqGrid({
                        datatype: 'local',
                        data: gridData,
                        editurl: 'clientArray',
                        colModel: columns,
                        loadonce: false,
                        autowidth: true,
                        shrinkToFit: false,
                        rownumbers: true,
                        multiselect: multiSelect,
                        multiboxonly:true,
                        cellEdit: false,
                        toppager: true,
                        cloneToTop: true,
                        gridview:true,
                        rowNum: 100,
                        viewrecords : true,
                        pager: "#pager" + gridId,
                        viewsortcols: viewSort,
                        cellsubmit: 'clientArray'
                    });
                }
```

Please help!! Thanks in Advance .  The Visibility column i must make it has checkbox .. its working for the column but in header i have to add .. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lY5s.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found**

```
                      "name":"visibility", 
                       "label":"<input role='checkbox' type='checkbox' id='grid'>Visibility",
                       "editable": true, 
                       "width":"200",
                       "edittype": "checkbox",
                       "editoptions": { value:"Y:N" }, 
                       "formatter": "checkbox", 
                       "formatoptions": { disabled: false}
```

we need to set *role* and *type* is checkbox .. so header will get checkbox